# List & Label: Getting ErrorCode -105 with Delphi VCL components

Tags: delphi, vcl, listlabel

I have a problem using the [List & Label components](https://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/report-generator-list-label-highlights/) with the Delphi VCL. When I'm accessing the `Design` method of the `TL20_` object, I get the following error code:

> error code -105 (license error)

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  llDriver: TL20_;
  res: Integer;
begin
  llDriver := TL20_.Create(Self);
  try
    llDriver.Language := ltDefaultLang;
    llDriver.LicensingInfo := 'xxxxxx';
    res := llDriver.Design(0, WindowHandle, '123', LL_PROJECT_LABEL, '123', False, True);
    ShowMessage(llDriver.LlGetErrortext(res));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(llDriver);
  end;
end;
```

Using the same license key with a Python application on the same PC works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will need to contact the component vendor about your issue, this question is not fit for SO.

Comment: Are you able to run the samples that follows the installation? Is the path to the dll's in your environment path? What did the vendor say?

Comment: Looking at the site the license seems to be for one user *and one development environment* (for example if you are using it for pascal and want to use it for C++ you need to uninstall and reinstall) although the license can be amended by the vendor. Since you are using it with Python, my guess is that your license is 'used up' and won't work with VCL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `LicensingInfo` property of the VCL component to the value that can be found in the personal license information file that comes with the installation.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i have set the LicensingInfo property. I used the same key that works well with the Python application... With the VCL components it doesn't work.